# "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported." while Loading url in webVIew

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-webview, android-websettings, android-webview-javascript

am trying to launch a URl in webView But it is throwing an error like

> "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported."

I have tried adding setUseWideViewPort to webview but didnot work
We also tried  by adding below line to web source code but didnot work

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=high-dpi" />
```

Can you help me out to fix this issue thank you